# permission denied error in docker

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I create the docker image but I am trying to give a parameter to the docker image but I am getting an  permission denied error on my entry.sh file.

Docker File:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER  ravat  
RUN mkdir -p /home/ravata/Desktop/DockerDemo/
RUN echo “Hello Apache server on Ubuntu Docker” > /home/ravata/Desktop/DockerDemo/index.html
COPY entry.sh .
CMD /bin/bash entry.sh
```

enrty.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
echo $1
```

I built the docker image with command:- `docker build -t docker-demo .`
Now I am trying to provide parameter to docker Image to run :- `docker run -ti docker-demo /entry.sh ravat`

Comment: Set a user with USER in your docker file and then check that the file is executable for that user.

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Build the image without the command and then log into the container and run the command manually. This will give you a greater indication of what is going on. If necessary, chown/chmod the file to execute it. Then reflect the steps taken to create your docker file and build the image.

Comment: I didn't get you, can please elaborate because I am totally new on docker.

Comment: Can you please include the command you are running and the output of the error? We shouldn't need to interpret what "permission denied error" means. Just give the log output and any other relevant commands and files so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: exec: "/entry.sh": permission denied
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container b894a8b5dd9e9339c27fde3da18ba8653abd1cca7ab1484e1fd6c83f03ce6a51: [8] System error: exec: "/entry.sh": permission denied

Answer (score 1):

This error isn't actually a Docker error, it's likely the enrty.sh script was missing the execution bit.

You can ensure the file is executable by running `chmod +x entry.sh`.

Like this:

```bash
% docker run -ti docker-demo /entry.sh ravat
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/entry.sh": permission denied: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled

% chmod +x entry.sh
% docker build --quiet -t docker-demo .
sha256:klsjhdfkjhsdkfjhsdjfnkwenfkjbn22332223lkjhn24nl23n
% docker run -ti docker-demo /entry.sh ravat
ravat
```