# Wordpress cli permission denied error in docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, wordpress-rest-api

I am creating a image of `wordpress cli` using `wordpress` image.

Here the Dockerfile I am using for the image:

```
FROM wordpress:latest
RUN cd /tmp && echo "Installing WP-CLI" && curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar && chmod +x wp-cli.phar && echo "Permission setted" && mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp && echo "file moved" && chmod +x /var/www/html && echo "success permission" && wp core install --path= `/var/www/html`  --allow-root && echo "Setting Username and Password" && wp core install --url="localhost"  --title="My First Blog" --admin_user="username" --admin_password="password" --admin_email="admin@mail.com"
```

But it shows error. I have added the steps showing in the Output.

```
Step 1/7 : FROM wordpress:latest
 ---> fc03dc56d371
Step 2/7 : RUN cd /tmp && echo "Installing WP-CLI" && curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar && chmod +x wp-cli.phar && echo "Permission setted" && mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp && echo "file moved" && chmod +x /var/www/html && echo "success permission" && wp core install --path= `/var/www/html`  --allow-root && echo "wp success" && wp cache set my_key my_value my_group 300
 ---> Running in b9b293a11137
Installing WP-CLI
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 5412k  100 5412k    0     0   250k      0  0:00:21  0:00:21 --:--:--  316k
Permission setted
file moved
success permission
/bin/sh: 1: /var/www/html: Permission denied
Error: This does not seem to be a WordPress installation.
Pass --path=`path/to/wordpress` or run `wp core download`.
```

I don't know how to fix permission error in Docker. I used `chmod` but it fails.I tried this link [permission denied error in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44881489/permission-denied-error-in-docker) . But none has answered yet. Help me with some solutions.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? This is the exact error I am having.